# Options in bitbake to link files to the boot partition

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

I have a bitbake configuration that generates two partitions, the BOOT (FAT) partition containing uBoot, uEnv.txt, etc. and a root file system that gets mounted read-only.  There may be instances where the filesystem isn't a separate partition, but rather a ramdisk, so I'm trying to enforce a design pattern that works in both instances:

What I'm trying to do is provide some of the files in the root filesystem as links to locations on the SD card.  This way I can build a single SD card image and the minor edits for node IDs or names can be easily tweaked by end-users.  So for example, if `/etc/special_config.conf` would be a useful one, then rather than store it on the read-only partition, a link would be created pointing back to the real file on the BOOT partition.

So far I've tried making a recipe that, for that case, does the following:

```
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES += "special_config.conf"

do_install () {
    ln -s /media/BOOT/special_config.conf \
        ${D}${sysconfigdir}/special_config.conf
}
```

This doesn't seem to do anything.  The `IMAGE_BOOT_FILES` doesn't collect the `special_config.conf` file into the BOOT partition, as if when the system image gets populated all of those changes get wiped out.

Has anyone seen a clever way to enforce this kind of behavior in BitBake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you get your `${sysconfdir}/special_config.conf` symlink in the image (via a package built from recipe mentioned), but you don't get the `special_config.conf` file on your BOOT partition using `wic` image fstype.

If that's the case, then the only problem is that you define `IMAGE_BOOT_FILES` in the *package* recipe, rather than defining it in the *image* recipe, because this variable is only evaluated at image build time. So drop that from your config file recipe and add it to the image recipe, it should work this way.